# Lightbox Not Working on AJAX Load Parts

Tags: javascript, jquery, ajax

I have a page with 5 pictures and a button to load more using AJAX. I am loading the rest of the pictures using this script:

```
<script type="text/javascript">
                        $(document).ready(function(){
                            $("#loadmorebutton").click(function (){
                                $('#loadmorebutton').html('<img src="<?php bloginfo('template_url'); ?>/img/ajax-loader.gif" />');
                                $.ajax({
                                    url: "<?php bloginfo('template_url'); ?>/includes/loadmore.php?lastid=" + $(".postitem:last").attr("id"),
                                    success: function(html){
                                        if(html){
                                            $("#wallPosts").append(html);
                                            $('#loadmorebutton').html('Load More');
                                        }else{
                                            $('#loadmorebutton').replaceWith('<center>No more posts to show.</center>');
                                        }
                                    }
                                });
                            });
                        });
                    </script>
```

First, 5 pictures are displayed and when a user clicks on older posts more 5 are loaded. Now my problem is that although all the pictures have the same code/class/structure, lightbox works only on the first 5 pictures, not on the one loaded by AJAX. Someone can help me with this problem?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
$(document).ready(function(){
    $("#loadmorebutton").live('click', function (){
        $('#loadmorebutton').html('<img src="<?php bloginfo('template_url'); ?>/img/ajax-loader.gif" />');
        $.ajax({
            url: "<?php bloginfo('template_url'); ?>/includes/loadmore.php?lastid=" + $(".postitem:last").attr("id"),
            success: function(html){
                if(html){
                    $("#wallPosts").append(html);
                    $('#loadmorebutton').html('Load More');
                }else{
                    $('#loadmorebutton').replaceWith('<center>No more posts to show.</center>');
                }
            }
        });
    });
});
```

Use jQuery.Live() to attach events to objects that will be added to the page via AJAX. Otherwise the events only tie into the elements on the page when the function is called. Documentation can be found [here](http://api.jquery.com/live/)

Comment: Can you also help me convert this one?

'$(document).ready(function () {
    $('#commentBox<?php echo $row['
    id ']; ?>').hide();
    $('#comment<?php echo $row['
    id ']; ?>').click(function () {
        $('#commentBox<?php echo $row['
        id ']; ?>').show();
    });
});'

Comment: Are you trying to make each comment box hide as they are loaded or are you doing this through css? I would default the css to display:none and then you don't need the hide line and just use  the following in your document.ready()
`$('#comment<?php echo $row[' id ']; ?>').live('click', function () { $('#commentBox<?php echo $row[' id ']; ?>').show();
});`

Comment: If this solved your problem please mark it as the answer; otherwise the question will continue to show up as unanswered.